# How to know Active sessions in Drupal?

Tags: 7, sessions

Is there any way to find my opened/active sessions and close them in Drupal? If there is already a session for the logged-in user, a notification like the following should be shown.

> Open in 1 other location - Details

Similarly as administrator user, I would like to view active sessions for all users. I know that all sessions are stored in the *sessions* table. I can retrieve them by creating a custom module, but I wonder if there is a module available for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a module for that called [Active Sessions](https://www.drupal.org/project/active_sessions)

> Active Session is a module that allows a user to see if there is more than one session opened for their user and allows them (with permissions) to end other sessions belonging to their user. There is also an interface where a user with permissions can view all active sessions and close them.
>
> Active Session creates a block that, by default, is placed in the footer of the page for users with 'view own sessions' or 'view all sessions' permissions to see and get more details about the sessions.

Images from module page
[image] [image]